# How to allow html tags in php variable [wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress

Please consider the example below:

I have a variabe

```
 $var ="<-b> hello <-/b>";
```

when I echo it, it shows same as `<-b> hello <-/b>`.

But I want it to render HTML and show result as bold text like: **hello**

How to do this in wordpress?

Comment: What ever you have in the variable will be echo'd. IE: `$var='&amp;This'` will echo to `&this`. `$var = '<strong>This Text</strong>';` will echo to a bolded text reading `This Text`

Comment: in wordpress its not echoing out html

Comment: "<-b>" isn't HTML. "<b>" is. So raveenanigam's answer should be valid.

Comment: In which wordpress page are you trying to echo from ? Are you sure that the page is being called?

Comment: @lpeharda `<b>` is HTML. Its deprecated but its still HTML. Its what was used before `<strong>` etc. It was used with `<u>` and `<i>` for underlining and italics respectively.

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer I was referring to his obvious mistake that no one commented on and not which HTML tag should he use

Answer (score -1):

Use `<b>` tags, e.g.,

```
$var ="<b>hello</b>";
```